# "Expression Implicity Coerced from 'String?' to Any" JSON Swift 3

Tags: json, swift

Hi I have the below JSON code I would like to parse

```
"data":{
            "date":"November 30th, 2016",
            "personality":"Larry",
            "comment":"Saw the homie today"
},
```

I'm doing this in my viewDidLoad

```
let url=URL(string:"http://IP-ADDRESS/info.php")

        do {
            let allNotificationsData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
            let allNotication = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allNotificationsData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
            if let arrJSON = allNotication["notifications"] {
                for index in 0...arrJSON.count-1 {
                    let aObject = arrJSON[index] as? [String: AnyObject]
                    //let name = aObject?["data"]!

                    if let jsonResponse = aObject,
                        let info = jsonResponse["data"] {
                        // Makes sense to check if count > 0 if you're not sure, but...
                        let transaction_id: String? = info["personality"] as? String
                        print(transaction_id)
                        // Do whatever else you need here
                    }
```

Which seems to be fine but console returns below. Not sure while "nil" but I just want it show me "date" in the JSON file itself only in the console. Eventually I'll need it to catch an array of dates, not sure how I'll do that but I'm working on it. Let me know if you know what I'm doing wrong. It has to be something with optional.

Comment: You Data dictionary Contains `person` key not `personality` key.

Comment: @NiravD Typo, it's really "personality"

Comment: Consider that in Swift 3 the (JSON) dictionary type is `[String:Any]`

Comment: @vadian You can't convert a string to [String Any]

Comment: I didn't write anything about converting.

Comment: @vadian It has to be this line but what am I doing wrong? "                        let accessToken:String! = tokenDict["comment"] as! [String: Any]"

Comment: According to the JSON `comment` is doubtless a string: `let accessToken = tokenDict["comment"] as! String`. Do not annotate types the compiler can infer (better).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the parent object of `data` is an array (your code suggests that) you can get all `data` objects in an array with:

```
   do {
        let allNotificationsData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
        let allNotification = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allNotificationsData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
        if let arrJSON = allNotification["notifications"] as? [[String:Any]] {
           let infoArray = arrJSON.flatMap { $0["data"] }  
        }

        ...

      }
```

The benefit of `flatMap` is it ignores `nil` values.

If you want to access the `comment` value of the first item in the array write

```
let comment = (infoArray[0] as! [String:Any])["comment"] as! String
```

Comment: Look at my next post.